# SQL Spool file doesn't show all the results from the query

Tags: oracle, shell, unix, sqlplus, spool

I have the following sql:

```
select
CASE
          WHEN Count(*) > 1
              THEN 'Archiving task was executed succesfully!'
              ELSE 'Archiving task was not executed succesfully for day: ' || Days
          END CASE
from
(select substr(table_name,12,8) as Days from user_tables
where table_name like 'CDR_DETAIL_%' AND SubStr(table_name,12,8) IN ( SELECT * FROM tmp_archive_process_ict )
OR SubStr(table_name,12,8) IS null
order by 1 asc )
where rownum <= 7
GROUP BY Days
;
```

That returns the following result in sql tools:

```
CASE
Archiving task was not executed succesfully for day: 20130819
Archiving task was executed succesfully!
Archiving task was not executed succesfully for day: 20130821
Archiving task was not executed succesfully for day: 20130820
```

Using sqlplus in a shell, i am trying to return the result from the sql previously shown, into a file:

Part of unix shell:

```
#Make oracle conneciton
-oracle connection sqlplus

SET PAGESIZE 0;
SET ECHO OFF;
SET SPACE 0;
SET FEEDBACK OFF;
SET HEADING OFF;

SPOOL /bmd/mail_check.txt

select
CASE
          WHEN Count(*) > 1
              THEN 'Archiving task was executed succesfully!'
              ELSE 'Archiving task was not executed succesfully for day: ' || Days
          END CASE
from
(select substr(table_name,12,8) as Days from user_tables
where table_name like 'CDR_DETAIL_%' AND SubStr(table_name,12,8) IN ( SELECT * FROM tmp_archive_process_ict )
OR SubStr(table_name,12,8) IS null
order by 1 asc )
where rownum <= 7
GROUP BY Days
;

SPOOL OFF;
EXIT;
EOF
```

The script works, it generates the file but when i check the file ( cat /bmd/mail_check.txt ) it shows me just:

```
Archiving task was executed succesfully!
```

I don't understand why it doesn't show me the other results from the sql select into the file specified.:

```
Archiving task was not executed succesfully for day: 20130819
Archiving task was not executed succesfully for day: 20130821
Archiving task was not executed succesfully for day: 20130820
```

What i am doing wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Best regards,

Comment: shouldn't be the "WHEN Count(*) >= 1" ?? (adding the 'equal', so with 1 will be also displayed correctly)

Comment: No. It should be with >. But the file created with spool, doesn't contain the other results. Just the one that was executed succesfully!

Comment: Just to confirm, you use the right database credentials, when you spool?

Comment: Yes. The file is created. The file contains just " Archiving task was executed succesfully! " and not the other columns.

Comment: Since your query uses user_tables, results are likely to vary for different users. SPOOL just redirects the query output to the file. My guess is, the user and password you give is referring a different schema, than you expect. In SQL*Plus , lets first run the query manually.. Also after you run the query, you can even try spooling too explicitly..

Comment: Assuming it is the same user and data, are you sure you aren't modifying the file later in the script? Or redirecting (part of) the output to it as well - you haven't shown the `sqlplus ... <<EOF` part. Just a thought. You can add more output to see if it's the query or something else, maybe a `prompt before` and `prompt after` either side of the `select`?

Comment: Ok. Guess what. When i created the temporary table tmp_archive_process_ict, i didn't press commit! :).
The sql just returned the true condition, the other conditions were from the temporary table.

Now it shows me the desired result. Noob, noob! :)

Thank you very much for your responses.